# Where can I find Information about small businesses in Europe who formed 'co-op' currency & traded among each other between WW1/2?

Tags: 20th-century, europe

Several years ago I read an essay on a small/independent website about companies in Europe which got together during the hyper-inflationary 1920s & 30s and negotiated amongst each other for structuring semi-closed-loop trade of goods. They might've done straight barter, but IIRC they created their own currency for use in this private trade agreement. These were industrial and possibly some agricultural businesses, and relatively-small ones.

At least according to the libertarian slant in this essay, they were able to mitigate a substantial amount of the inflation happening with the German Mark and other currencies that were pegged/floated to it, and possibly to others in western/central Europe.

I think most of these companies were in Germany and Austria...maybe some neighboring countries too.

I tried searching the web for it, to no avail. Any recollection?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notgeld might be a place to start

Comment: @Jan If _Notgeld_ is the origin of OP's story, then things got quite garbled.